# New permission's model and RemoteViewsFactory

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, remoteview, android-appcompat

I am trying to use the new Android 6's permission model for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

but i get the exception

> *java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10153 does not have android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS*

in the `onDataSetChanged()` of my RemoteViewsFactory when I call

```
Settings.canDrawOverlays(mContext))
```

**Log:**

> java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10153 does not have
>   android.permission.UPDATE_APP_OPS_STATS.
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
>               at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub$Proxy.checkOperation(IAppOpsService.java:327)
>               at android.app.AppOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.java:1523)
>               at android.provider.Settings.isCallingPackageAllowedToPerformAppOpsProtectedOperation(Settings.java:8425)
>               at android.provider.Settings.isCallingPackageAllowedToDrawOverlays(Settings.java:8385)
>               at android.provider.Settings.canDrawOverlays(Settings.java:1432)

Can someone explain to me this exception?

**UPDATE**

Temporarily solved calling `canDrawOverlays()` from a service started from inside `onDataSetChanged()` of the RemoteViewsFactory

Comment: That's odd. Is your app uid 10153? What device or emulator are you using to test this?

Comment: I get this on real device Nexus 5 with the M Preview, and the same on emulator Nexus 5 with API 23.

Comment: The images for 6.0 final [were released today](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), so you might try updating to 6.0 final on the Nexus 5 and see what happens.

Comment: Another thing that you might try is calling `canDrawOverlays()` from someplace else (e.g., launcher activity) and see what happens. I haven't used the method yet myself, though I need to soonish.

Comment: In the same app calling canDrawOverlays() from an Activity works fine. I will try on final release of Android 6 soon.

Comment: skipped the exception calling canDrawOverlays() from a service started from inside onDataSetChanged() of the RemoteViewsFactory

Comment: @GPack i call this method inside my service but still have exception. In your case calling from service doesn't produce exception?

Comment: @x90 yes moving the call inside a service doesnt get the exception for me

Answer (score 0):

**Settings.canDrawOverlays**,**AppOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow** and **Setting.System.canWrite** can cause this kind of crashes in various cases (probably only on Android 6.x) , as reported here:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196372
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227835 .

The workaround I've found is to run them all on the UI thread using a handler, and wait for the result on the thread you are working on. Here's an example for the case of extending of NotificationListenerService :

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
   final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do the check of Settings.canDrawOverlays here.
            // notify that the result of the check was done
        }
    });
    //wait for result of the handler
```